# Docker Compose - Set mount target to volume specified in dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

- Is there any way to achieve this?
- Is there any reason why this might be a bad idea?
- Is there a better way?

---

Dockerfile example:

```
FROM someImage

VOLUME "/var/lib/myContainerVol/"
```

docker-compose.yml example:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    myService:
        build: .
        volumes:
            - myHostVol:<AS DEFINED IN DOCKERFILE>

volumes:
    myHostVol:
```

I guess the question could be rephrased for the docker cli:

`docker run --mount type=volume,src=myHostVol,target=<AS DEFINED IN DOCKERFILE>`

Comment: your question is unclear,  pls explain what you actually trying to achieve and what error you are getting.

Comment: Your dockerfile could contain several volumes definitions, some of them even inherited from parent images. How would docker-compose choose the correct target for your named volume ? `as defined in dockerfile` is the path to the target dir, just write it down.

Comment: @Zeitounator , Yeah I do understand that and I don't want to inherit all volumes that might be in an image. I just want compose to inherit and target the ones I've specified in my own dockerfile, so that I don't have to bother updating my compose file if I update the dockerfile. 

Meaning, if I change "/var/lib/myContainerVol/" to something else. My compose file would still work without having to be updated.